# Script to change windows firewall remote address excluding rules with localsubnets

Tags: powershell

I am trying to expand a script I wrote (and got help on from users on SO). Its a Windows powershell script that adds IP's to the Remote Address list on the Windows firewall.

I am trying to get it to exclude any firewall rules where the remote address is already specified as "LocalSubnet".

Here is what I have so far, currently when I run it with write-host instead of the actual command, it displays nothing.

```
#This script will update remote address rules with the specified IP scope(s)
$displayname = read-host "Enter firewall rule display name"
$name = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $displayname |Where-Object {$_.Direction -eq "Inbound"}
$exclusion =  Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $displayname |Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter
$ips = @()
do {
 $input = (Read-Host "Please enter IP address")
 if ($input -ne '') {$ips += $input}
}
until ($input -eq '')

foreach ($r in $name)
{
    foreach ($e in $exclusion){
        if ($e.remoteaddress -NotMatch "LocalSubnet") {continue}
    #Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $r.DisplayName -RemoteAddress $ips
    write-host $r.Displayname $ips
    }
}
```

I am lost on the nested loop...do I even need the nested loop? I tried some while and do loops as well to no avail.

@Matt - Thanks! Here is the correct script.

```
#This script will update remote address rules with the specified IP scope(s)
$displayname = read-host "Enter firewall rule display name"
$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $displayname | Where-Object {$_.Direction -eq "Inbound" -and ($_ | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter).RemoteAddress -ne "LocalSubnet" }
$ips = @()
do {
 $answer = (Read-Host "Please enter IP address")
 if ($answer -ne '') {$ips += $answer}
}
until ($answer -eq '')

foreach ($rule in $rules)
    {

    #Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $r.DisplayName -RemoteAddress $ips
    write-host $rule.Displayname $ips

}
```

Comment: Whoops caught a spelling mistake, I get output now. But it looks like it just loops through them all regardless of the NotMatch on "LocalSubnet".

Comment: Looks like I was getting inbound and outbound rules fixed script. Think its still not processing the nested loop.

Comment: So you are updating all `$r` in `$name` where the remote address is not LocalSubnet?

Comment: When I search for a rule that has two inbound objects, instead of write-host just printing the one rule that does not have "LocalSubnet" in the remote address field, I get both rules, the one with "LocalSubnet" and the one with "Any" in the remote address field. Not sure what I am doing wrong with the nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will remove this if I am wrong but code in comments is terrible. I am changing the names of the variables to have more meaning. The inner loop you have is not required and would generate extra output. All we do here is build the condition into the `Where-Object`. This removes the exclusions logic you were trying to do.

```
$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $displayname | 
    Where-Object {$_.Direction -eq "Inbound" -and ($_ | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter).RemoteAddress -ne "LocalSubnet" }

# get ips .....

foreach ($rule in $rules)
{
    # Do Stuff
}
```

`$rules` should now only be the ones you need to action.

---

**Note:** Don't use `$input` as a variable name. It is a reserved name in PowerShell. See about_automatic_variables for more information. `$answer` or `$result` would suffice in this case.

Comment: @Matt - your update works, I will digest that a bit in regards to the where-object command. I will post the updated script above.

Comment: @FrodeF. Cool beans. I never played with PS5 cmdlets much.

Comment: @FrodeF. Looks like they are in different sets. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554860(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: Yeah you're right. Guess I used this without Name/Displayname last time. That's what you get with bad memory and stackoverflow iOS-app. :-)

Comment: So you are seeing results where "localsubnet" is there?

Comment: @Matt - nope, I just really need more coffee. There actually are no local subnet rules in the query I ran, there are "Local Subnet 6" rules though for IPV6, so I just changed it around and it works. Sorry! It works fine!

Comment: Ah ok. I would have used `-notlike "localsubnet*"` in that case.